# efilogin-helper running continuously at high cpu on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, process, cpu-usage, macos-sierra

There is a process launched by launchd called efilogin-helper running as root, which is continuously running at high CPU load (60% to 120%)

Do you know what this process is and how I can get it under control?

There is surprisingly little information on Google.

Also, what would be a good debug method to go about solving these sorts of issues myself?

Comment: I've tried every solution I've read about here and elsewhere, including deleting my high res desktop background, but this is still happening on my Macbook Pro Retina (10.13.5). I'll notice my fan starting and stopping repeatedly and when I check activity monitor, there's efilogin-helper with an energy impact > 100. IT disappears from the top spot, and then reappears, over and over. The only thing that works reliably in my experience is a restart. Battery impact is huge--makes it impossible to work for more than three hours without power.

Comment: @Moderators This should be migrated SuperUser or Ask Different

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to system preferences => Desktop & Screen Saver

Select Apple->Desktop Pictures and choose the first option.

efilogin-helper will eventually quit after about a minute and no longer be a problem.

Bizarre but true!

(Once you have confirmed that you have indeed resolved the issue you can then probably reselect your preferred wallpaper without a problem.)

Comment: Do you have Artpip installed by any chance? efilogin-helper started acting up when Artpip updated itself.

Comment: It is definitely caused by the latest Artpip update

Comment: @sebnukem - thanks for your comment. I don't have Artpip installed nor anything like that to dynamically change desktop. I did change the wallpaper to a jpeg that I took but that is all. Pretty much a vanilla install.

Comment: Did not resolve the issue for me: when I re-activate changing desktop background, the issuer re-appears

Comment: "The first option" being "at login?"

Comment: No artpip installed here, and this fixed it, after an upgrade to high sierra.  smh.

Comment: This trick fixed it for me for a while, but then it came back exactly as before. I am on 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

Answer (score 3):

For those that are truly tired of this, and want to never see that process started automatically again:

1. restart into recovery > terminal in recovery mode
2. run `csrutil disable`
3. restart into normal mode
4. `cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons` (or something like that)
5. run `rm -f com.apple.efi...plist` (you can find the one I'm talking about
   by running `grep -l efilog *` )
6. boot into recovery again > terminal in recovery mode
7. run `csrutil enable`
8. restart into normal
9. **GET YOUR COMPUTER BACK**

This *may* have implications related to changing your wallpaper, IDK, and IDC, 20gb RAM / 100% CPU usage is unacceptable on a process that's supposed to help with wallpaper switching.

Comment: I used this answer about four months ago. It works but unfortunately can cause an unwanted side-effect: the login screen when you first power up eventually stops showing the icons and usernames of the available accounts. Instead it shows generic icons and the text "[Update Needed]" under each one. You can still log in, but if there are multiple users you have to guess which icon to click. This might only happen with FileVault enabled, which I have. I'm guessing that efilogin-helper bakes the icons and usernames into the pre-filevault login screen image.

Answer (score 2):

Artpip app developer here - I don't have enough reputation to comment on the other answer, but it looks like 2.2.1 introduced a bug for some users where it the background would be set too often, which may have caused the issue others were seeing, though I haven't seen it myself.

As of 2.2.4 this should be fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: No inconvenience installed to me because I don't have Artpip. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hi Artpip developer! I have 2.4.2 and I'm still seeing this.

Comment: Me too! Artpip 2.4.2.

Comment: Me too, also with 2.4.2.

Comment: Me too, also with 2.4.2. - I tried to wait it out, but at this point i have to sadly uninstall

Comment: We have deployed another fixed and hopefully you should now not see this as of 2.4.3.

To actually answer the original question - in the case of Artpip there was a bug that caused the desktop background to be set too often. Hopefully that might provide some insight into the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this issue as well on my MBP. It is running High Sierra 10.13.6.

I fixed the issue by switching my background to a solid color. I followed the same steps as @T33C but instead I used a solid background. Fixed the issue and got my battery back